# ClickHouse - How to calculate total duration in state

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table that contains a record each time a state change occurs.  I am trying to write a query where I can provide a start and end time and it will return the total amount of time that was spent in each state.  Since records are only written when there is a change, the state at the start of the query interval should be taken from the previous record.

Here is an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE ts_vals (name String, ts DateTime, val Int32) ENGINE=Memory;

INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 09:50:00'), 1);
INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E002', toDateTime('2023-12-01 09:59:00'), 1);
INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:02:00'), 2);
INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:03:00'), 1);
INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:04:00'), 3);
INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:08:00'), 1);
INSERT INTO ts_vals VALUES ('E002', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:14:00'), 1);
```

If I wanted to know the total durations from 2023-12-1 10:00 to 2023-12-1 10:05, I would expect the following results:

| name | val | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E001 | 1 | 180 seconds |
| E001 | 2 | 60 seconds |
| E001 | 3 | 60 seconds |
| E002 | 1 | 300 seconds |

I've tried various combinations of FILL and WINDOW functions but I can't seem to get the results I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
We get next timestamp for each record within each name first (ts_next).
Then we adjust a time interval for each record accordingly and sum the interval durations in seconds for each (name, val) pair finally.

```
WITH
  toDateTime ('2023-12-01 10:00:00') as ts_start
, toDateTime ('2023-12-01 10:05:00') as ts_end
SELECT 
  name
, val
, sum (ts_end_interval - ts_start_interval) as duration
FROM
(
SELECT 
  *
-- lead (ts, 1) emulation
, any (cast (ts, 'Nullable (DateTime)')) over (partition by name order by ts rows between 1 following and 1 following)
    as ts_next
, if (ts < ts_start, ts_start, ts)
    as ts_start_interval    
, coalesce (ts_next, ts_end)
    as ts_end_interval  
FROM VALUES 
(
  'name String, ts DateTime, val Int32'
, ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 09:50:00'), 1)
, ('E002', toDateTime('2023-12-01 09:59:00'), 1)
, ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:02:00'), 2)
, ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:03:00'), 1)
, ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:04:00'), 3)
, ('E001', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:08:00'), 1)
, ('E002', toDateTime('2023-12-01 10:14:00'), 1)
)
WHERE ts < ts_end
)
WHERE ts_end_interval > ts_start
GROUP BY name, val
ORDER BY name, val
```

The result is:

```
|name|val|duration|
|----|---|--------|
|E001|1  |180     |
|E001|2  |60      |
|E001|3  |60      |
|E002|1  |300     |
```